# Find child element by xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

```
public WebElement findChildByXpath(WebElement parent, String xpath) {
    loggingService.timeMark("findChildByXpath", "begin. Xpath: " + xpath);

    String parentInnerHtml = parent.getAttribute("innerHTML"); // Uncomment for debug purpose.

    WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));

    String childInnerHtml = child.getAttribute("innerHTML"); // Uncomment for debug purpose.

    return child;
}
```

The problem with this code is that childInnerHtml gives me wrong result. I scrape numbers and they are equal.

I even suppose that my code is equal to **driver.findElement(By.xpath**.

Could you tell me whether my comment really finds a child or what to correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child XPath need to be a **relative** XPath. Normally this means the XPath expression is started with a dot `.` to make this XPath **relative** to the node it applied on. I.e. to be relative to the parent node. Otherwise Selenium will search for the given `xpath` (the parameter you passing to this method) starting from the top of the entire page.
So, if for example, the passed `xpath` is `"//span[@id='myId']"` it should be `".//span[@id='myId']"`.
Alternatevely you can add this dot `.` inside the `parent.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));` line to make it

```java
WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath("." + xpath));
```

But passing the `xpath` with the dot is more simple and clean way. Especially if the passed `xpath` is come complex expression like `"(//div[@class='myClass'])[5]//input"` - in this case automatically adding a dot before this expression may not work properly.